# What happens when replacing AsyncTask with new Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Quick Android question... What happens when you create a new AsyncTask that replaces an existing one? For example you have a simple activity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity{

    private MyTask myTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // first instance
        myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();

        // immediately replace first instance
        // assume the first instance hasn't finished yet
        myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();


    }
}
```

What happens to the first instance? does it run to completion? Is it garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Both instance will run separately upto task completetion.***

*When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread.*

*Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel.*

*Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.*

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: Nice answering Mr.Don  +10

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that first instance start at 0ms and end at 9 ms, then second instance at 3ms and end up at some other time so if you it will execute your code parallel in stack .

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask`s run serially, meaning they run one after another. When you set myTask to another `AsyncTask`, that doesn't get rid of the old one you just started, you just lose the reference to it. Now the 2nd `AsyncTask` is going to run after the first one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The instance won't be garbage collected until it the task finishes. Be aware that this could cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

**AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.**

Hence the two instance will run in separate thread without linking with one another and will run until completion.

Comment: Will this not cause IllegalStateException, i know in Java, trying to start a thread twice before the completion of the first will result in IllegalStateException, i am excepting the same behaviour. Love to try that and see the result..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is initially (in early Android OS versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations for a bunch of AsyncTasks. But later they fixed that and now the size is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously.
https://github.com/vitkhudenko/test_asynctask

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask run on UI thread and they are executed serially . Yaa, you will be going to get leaks there. Try running Memory analyzer tool here, you will get to know the about the retain heap here.

You can't run execute on single instance of AsyncTask like:

```
 myTask = new MyTask();
myTask.execute();
myTask.execute(); // Illegal
```

as, stated in the docs

**The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)**

ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

but what you are trying to do is quite legal.